# Create new tables when entity framework application is deployed or re-use existing ones

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I am developing an accounting app and I need a way to clear tables populated wit previous data and start over but not losing the data. My idea is that the table name is for example "Journal_01", then the client use that table in 1 month period and then I need to clear the table, save data for future reference and reports, and then create another one like "Journal_02". _01, _02 is the month in the accounting period, Is there a way I can create a table and have the mapping with entity framework app deployed? or is there a clever solution to solve the problem? thanks

Comment: In my opinion you would be better off adding the `JounralNumber` as a new part to your primary key.

Comment: It's not a good idea. Imagine, that you are going to select data for two months. Do you want to join two tables? And what about year?

Comment: Journal as new part of primary key? I dont get it, can u explain?